# Is There a Way to Post Spreadsheets in an Answer?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I have an answer which needs to calculate all possible combinations from a quest pool to determine what the most likely outcome of re-rolling a quest would be for the current combination of quests: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234120/53654

I've written a program to generate this information: http://ideone.com/hQbzZL Unfortunately the output is so large that it times out on online compilers. When I run the program locally it generates 2087 combinations, so I just don't know how to roll that into a post.

What I'd like to do is attach the generated .csv to the answer, so anyone who wants to can download and use the spreadsheet. Does StackExchange have any provision for doing this, or do I have to create an account on some shady 3rd party file sharing site in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Pretty sure SE doesn't support it.  Not all filesharing sites are shady, though.  Try jumpshare.

Comment: You could Google drive or dropbox. Both of these sites are well known and not shady.

Comment: @angussidney That's actually my preferred solution... but, I'd like to be able to do it without giving my email out to all creation... and that part I'm not sure about.

Comment: I think the better stance would be to allow for inline tables in the markdown.  Allowing users to directly attach files, aside from images which are already sanitized through imgr, opens a huge can of worms and would give spammers a new attack vector.

Comment: @zero298 Even if I could do tables the size of this table would well exceed the 30k characters allowable in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Format it like a preformatted text table and post it as a code block

In alternative upload your csv to google spreadsheets, share with everybody with a link, then use the sharing link.

In both cases two thousand combinations sounds like way too many for an answer; surely you can boil the information down to a more manageable amount?

Comment: Did you look at the question before saying that that it was too many? I'm [finding all possible combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of length 7 from a 36 element set. C(36, 7) = 8,347,680 I wrote a bunch of code to distill this down to 2,087 results. Anyway, I might could program this into a table, I'm not sure what the max length of an answer is... Speaking of answers, what would really make this a good one is if you could tell me how to share something from Google Drive without sharing my address...

Comment: It's times like this that I wish you could use runnable code snippets on Arqade.

Comment: @zero298 I strongly agree. This should be so simple.

Answer (score 3):

Markdown Tables are a [relatively new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/179041) addition to the Stack Exchange Engine, and a good solution for smaller datasets. Markdown like this:

```
| Table Headers         | Are Supported                      |
|-----------------------|------------------------------------|
| Some Formatting works | Like **Bold**                      |
|                       | *Italics*                          |
| (As do Blank cells ^) | And <strike>Strikethrough</strike> |
```

Results in this:

| Table Headers | Are Supported |
| --- | --- |
| Some Formatting works | Like **Bold** |
|  | *Italics* |
| (As do Blank cells ^) | And <strike>Strikethrough</strike> |

<sup>As a side-note, the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) site is great for getting the formatting right.</sup>

---

For larger datasets like your [example answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234120/28182), I would suggest either

1. Trimming down the data to only the information required, or if that is impossible:
2. Using a Google Sheets (or other cloud-hosted spreadsheet service), creating a 'Read Only' link, and linking to it in your answer.